# AWS - apiLambda vs defaultLambda

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I'm using `serverless` to deploy my `next.js` app in `aws`.
Can one tell the difference between `apiLambda` and `defaultLambda` in `aws`?
The following image is from aws managment console page:
[image]

This is my `serverless.yml` I have:

```
myApp:
  component: '@sls-next/serverless-component@1.17.0-alpha.12'
  inputs: 
    bucketName: myApp-site
    name:
      defaultLambda: myAppDefaultLambda
      apiLambda: myAppApiLambda
    useServerlessTraceTarget: true
```

Thanks

Comment: got any idea yet about the difference?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( ... I wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found the answer, you can read more at https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-nextjs-plugin

"The API handler and default handler packages are deployed separately, but each has a limit of 50 MB zipped or 250 MB uncompressed per AWS - see here and here. By design, there is currently only one Lambda@Edge for all page routes and one Lambda@Edge for all API routes. This could lead to code size issues especially if you have many API routes, SSR pages, etc."

So basically it seems you can customize lambda for pages (default lambda) and apis (api lamdbda).